# Is wearing LEDs dangerous?

Tags: led

Wearing 1 LED isn't much of a problem. It only requires a few volts and ~25mA of current. But what about 100+ LEDs? It depends on the number of LEDs in series or parallel (or both), but would it be enough to do serious harm to someone?

Comment: As long as the current doesn't need to pass through the human body, it will do no harm.

Comment: This is an electrical/electronic SE so I'm not sure anyone here could or should give you a complete *carte blanche* on high intensity monochromatic light. There exist [drugs](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/chem.201705349), for example, which are activated by such light.

Comment: Even one  5mm LED @ 20mA can damage the eye after some interval at some close range with mW/mm² power density on the retina being the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YES, there are potential dangers, and you'd have to take care of these in your design.

Assuming the LEDs are about 300mW each (30W total for 100)....then it's doubtful you could find any danger in the light output (unless close to the eye) or the power level (a 30W electric blanket).

How you **drive** and connect the LEDs may indeed present some health hazards:

1. If you drive too many in a string, then the drive voltages can get into the 50-70V range, and this could become hazardous
2. You have to carry battery power for your application, so the size and protection you provide to the battery and it's wiring would be important.
3. Even at low voltages you need to ensure the wiring is protected.

Comment: These days, "wearing" implies a possible "piercing". Wouldn't go there!

Comment: There are people who have put LEDs [subcutaneously](https://motherboard-images.vice.com/content-images/contentimage/27561/1447093895184780.JPG?resize=1050:*).

Comment: 300mW LEDs? 20mW is more typical for small red LEDs. 300mW is a high powered LED.

Comment: Another issue is heat. If you're driving hundreds of LEDs you are moving quite a bit of power. 100 20mA 1.2V LEDs is several watts of power. The 300mW LEDs you're talking about would make for much more total power. A power supply that puts out 30W will get quite warm, and could cause burns if it isn't heatsinked well.

Comment: "There are people who have put LEDs subcutaneously." Oh man, that's nasty. Why would somebody do that to themselves voluntarily? I mean if you need a pacemaker that's one thing, but the guy in that picture has like a 3cm incision! Gotta figure that HURTS. And did he use medical grade components?

Answer (score 1):

Wearables are not necessarily dangerous.  The Olds College Fashion Institute in my city participates in a(I believe yearly) [fashion show](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/calgary/calgary-fashion-technology-3d-1.3515294) that involves LED and EL wire accented fashions, more haute couture than daily wearable stuff, but there is at least [one brand providing microcontrollers and PCB mounted](https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/135) LEDs, drivers, sensors in OTS fashion wearable solutions.  Whether and how safe your own project would be would depend on a few things:

- Voltage and current - If voltage is kept low enough, circuits pose little danger to humans.  Individual LED dies only operate at 2.2V-4V, and it would take an exceptional situation for this voltage to be dangerous to a human.  Generally up to 40-50V can be considered "touch safe" for a dry human in a sensible situation, but broken skin, sweat, piercings, jewelry, can all change the impedance across your body and potentially make a given voltage more dangerous.  Some parts of voltage converters may be inductive and in some situations could output more than the source voltage, so it is not enough to say "I'm running off 3 AA batteries at 4.5V max, so I'm safe".  You have to know what each component of your circuit does, and choose appropriate types to the task and treat them correctly.  High currents can produce a lot of heat in a partial failure situation like a broken conductor partially connecting, so depending on how much you can limit your voltage and current, and the design of the garment, you may end up structuring your power distribution quite differently than you would in a device or structure installation.
- Circuit protection - Part of the point of using a microcontroller or control IC is to provide various forms of fault detection, so that in the event of a fault, voltage converters/drivers are shut down or cut off from the wearer.  Having intelligent output control limits the amount of the circuit that you have to be careful about insulating more heavily.  With really good fault detection, 12V wearables could probably be executed quite safely.  Without decent fault detection, there is a chance you could suffer a strong shock or burns.  Also in the circuit protection category are fail-safe devices like current/temperature fuses, crowbar circuits, over and under voltage and current shutdown and battery protection.
- Efficiency - Lack of efficiency means more potentially dangerous heat being produced, and also increases the size of voltage converters and batteries, which are a potential hazard in themselves.  For whatever run time you want to get out of your heartbeat sensing wedding dress or disco Stetson hat, you'll want to limit the amount of battery you need to carry as much as possible.
- Mechanical design - You've got to be very careful choosing your materials for weight, insulation flexibility and thickness, stranding, heat dissipation, user protection, light diffusion/optics, fit and comfort, and there are additional challenges like how to build a garment that can be washed and what precautions are necessary to protect the user in case of battery failure without having a large, conspicuous electronics pack.
- When humans are actually looking *at* LEDs, as Sunnyskyguy points out above, relatively low power levels produce great effect.  That said, high power LEDs can still have their place, as they can centralize maintenance to some degree and a variety of optics like lenses and fibre optics, as well as those provided by layers of different textiles.  Fibre optic points could be woven in and securely fastened as point light sources all over a garment, allowing safe washing by having them connect to a relatively hidden and removable power and control unit that houses and cools a few high power LEDs.  An efficient and well executed design should allow you to safely execute designs with quite considerable brightness, and as a few more engineers gradually become interested in the industry, I would imagine more intrinsically safe, easy to operate options will pop up.  Right now the only markets I'm aware of are the costume and EDM industries, children's shoes and experimental fashion, although there are some relatively high power electronic garments available in thermal clothing that could be considered a related industry.

In conclusion, use reasonable currents and voltages provided by correct converters with correct fault protections, good efficiency, a limited and safe battery solution, suitable strain relief, heat spreading and potting, suitable conductor stranding, insulation and termination types, well thought out optics, safe point brightness, intelligent control, suitable mounting, and you should have a safe design.  Add in modularity and/or waterproofing as necessary to provide an easier maintenance design.  This is quite a long list as you can see, and the ability to provide cheap, compact control and power sources has been relatively recent, so the industry appears to be in an early stage.